# FacebookAuthorizationException

Tags: android, facebook, api, authorization

I'm developing an app for Android. This app uses, as an alternative, authorization through Facebook. I've done everything the way ["Facebook Login Flow for Android"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) says.

After passing

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, callback);
```

call I enter

```
onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
```

several times. The 1st time with

```
session == OPENING, exception == null.
```

Then the Facebook authorization dialog appears, where I enter *valid* email and password. After that `onSessionStateChange()` is entered for the 2nd time, with

```
session == CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, exception == com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException.
```

So the session is never opened. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. The reason was the incorrect (or something was wrong with) facebook application id (specified in AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Heads up, he means the facebook application ID